# THREE.js checking how close the camera is to a mesh

Tags: three.js, raycasting

I have a mesh landscape in THREE.js that the camera points down at, I'd like to maintain a certain distance from that mesh (so if there's peaks in the terrain the camera moves further away).

I thought raycasting would be the correct way to start going about this (by getting the intersection distance) but all the examples I find relate to using mouse co-ordinates; when I try to set the origin as the camera position, and the direction co-ords to be the camera position but with a 0 on the Y axis (so camera up in the air facing down) the intersect results come up empty.

For example, on the render event I have:

```
t.o.ray.vector = new THREE.Vector3(t.o.camera.position.x, 0, t.o.camera.position.z );
t.o.ray.cast = new THREE.Raycaster(t.o.camera.position,t.o.ray.vector );
t.o.ray.intersect = t.o.ray.cast.intersectObject(object, true);
console.log(t.o.ray.intersect);
```

This results in an empty array, even when I'm moving the camera, the only way I can seem to get this to work is by using the examples that rely on mouse events.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised it was because that setting 0 as the Y property was not enough. I had assumed that the vector co-ordinate simply helped calculate the direction in which the ray was pointing in, but this doesn't seem to be the case. i.e. -:

```
t.o.ray.vector = new THREE.Vector3(t.o.camera.position.x, -1000, t.o.camera.position.z );
t.o.ray.vector.normalize();
t.o.ray.cast = new THREE.Raycaster(t.o.camera.position,t.o.ray.vector );
t.o.ray.intersect = t.o.ray.cast.intersectObject(t.Terrain.terrain, true);
```

Produces the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach:

```
console.log( t.o.camera.position.distanceTo(t.o.vector.position) );
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. This function would just retrieve the distance to the secondary vector; in my setup I had required to see where the camera intersects my terrain (as the height of the terrain varies) and get that point which is why the raycasting route was required. Cheers though!